# length function not giving output

Tags: powershell

`$select.Length` is not giving output. Please find code below:

```
clear
$filePath = "c:\temp\result.txt"
$select = Select-String -Pattern "Final result:" -Path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\Summary.txt' #| Out-File c:\pattern.txt
$select1 = Select-String -Pattern "Final result:" -Path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\Summary.txt' | Out-File D:\temp\pattern.txt
Write-Host($select.Length)

if ($select.Length -gt 0) {
    Write-Host 'Contains String'
    $select2 = Select-String -Pattern "Passed" -Path 'D:\temp\pattern.txt'

    if ($select2.Length -gt 0) {
        #Out-File C:\temp\result.txt $filePath -Append 
        New-Item $filePath -ItemType file
        'Success' | Out-File -FilePath $filePath -Append   
    } else {
        New-Item $filePath -ItemType file
        'Failed' | Out-File -FilePath $filePath -Append  
    }
} else {
    Write-Host 'Does not contain String'
}
```

Ideally it should generate file with success as text in result.txt, but it's not working. I'm not getting any error.

Comment: you have to pipe something to out-file. at the moment out-file will write nothing

Comment: that is ok atleast it should go inside iam not getting anything on write-host($select.length)

Comment: what do you what to know with length? How many times it match?

Comment: i want to know id data exists it should update file with sucess or failure , i updated code but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$select` does not contain type `[String]`, which I assume is what you expect to have the property `Length`. Instead, use `$select.Line.Length`, where `$select.Line` is the matched line. Repeat for `$select2`

[image: Get-Member shows Line property]

- `$select1` - don't pipe to out file at the same time as assigning variable.  I think below gets you what you want and avoids that.

---

```
$select = Select-String -Pattern "Final result:" -Path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\Summary.txt'

# This outputs the matching line only
$select.Line |Out-File D:\temp\pattern.txt
```

Comment: awesome it worked , thanks  a lot i marked it as answer

Comment: @deepti Glad to hear it's sorted. Highly recommend using `Get-Member` to interact with different variables and find out what you can do with them.... didn't know that `Select-String` returned type `MatchInfo` and had the properties `Line` and `LineNumber` until I ran that command.

Answer (score 1):

this will count the matches:

```
$select2.Matches.Count
```