# PowerShell length function

Tags: sql, powershell

Just yesterday I posted a question for getting the length of a text file. It was working perfectly. I haven't changed anything, but still I am unable to get the length of `$select1`.

```bsh
Param([string]$servername)

$filePath1 = "D:\temp\result.txt"

try {
  $SqlQuery = "select SUBSTRING(CONVERT(sysname, SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')),0,CHARINDEX('.',convert(sysname,SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')),0))"
  $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

  $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $Servername; Database = master; Integrated Security = SSPI;"
  #write-host $SqlConnection.ConnectionString
  $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
  $SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
  $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
  $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
  $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
  $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
  $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
  $version = $DataSet.Tables[0].rows[0].Column1
  #Write-Host $version
  $DataSet.Tables[0] | Out-File "C:\temp\version.csv"

  switch -exact ($version) {
    '8'  {$version = 80}    # SQL Server 2000 =  8.00.xxxx
    '9'  {$version = 90}    # SQL Server 2005 =  9.00.xxxx
    '10' {$version = 100}   # SQL Server 2008 = 10.00.xxxx
    '11' {$version = 110}   # SQL Server 2012 = 11.00.xxxx
    '12' {$version = 120}   # SQL Server 2014 = 12.00.xxxx
    '13' {$version = 130}   # SQL Server 2016 = 13.00.xxxx
  }

  Write-Host $version
  $filePath="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\$version\Setup Bootstrap\Log\Summary.txt"
  Write-Host $filePath

  $select = Select-String -Pattern "Final result:" -Path $filePath #| Out-File c:\pattern.txt
  $select1 = Select-String -Pattern "Final result:" -Path $filePath | Out-File D:\temp\pattern.txt

  Write-Host($select1.Line.Length)
  Write-Host($select1.Matches.Count)

  if ($select1.Line.Length -gt 0) {
  #   Write-Host 'Contains String'
    $select2 = Select-String -Pattern "Passed" -Path 'D:\temp\pattern.txt'
    Write-Host($select2.Line.Length)
    if ($select2.Line.Length -gt 0) {
      Out-File -FilePath $filePath1
      'Success'| Out-File -FilePath $filePath1
    } else {
      Out-File -FilePath $filePath1
      'failed'| Out-File -FilePath $filePath1
    }
  } else {
    Write-Host 'Does not contain String'
  }
} catch {
  Write-Host -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor White "Fail"
  $errText =  $Error[0].ToString()

  if ($errText.Contains("network-related")) {
    Write-Host "Connection Error. Check server name, port, firewall."
  }

  Write-Host $errText
  continue
}
```

Loop is not working, it was working till yesterday.

```
Write-Host($select1.Line.Length)
Write-Host($select1.Matches.Count)

if($select1.Line.Length -gt 0) {
#  Write-Host 'Contains String'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [length function not giving output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44902741/length-function-not-giving-output)

Comment: As in previous case, don't use `Out-File` when assigning a variable. Check your line starting `$select1=`

Comment: removed out file still not working 
$select1=Select-String -Pattern "Final result:" -Path $filePath #|Out-File D:\temp\pattern.txt

Comment: @ gms0ulman yesterday my output was having single line, now its 2 line thats why not working how to iterate $select1 ,and how to remove spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any issue with the posted code but still if you are not getting any result then most probably the pattern you mentioned isn't matching `-Pattern "Final result:"`. You probably want to check that once. You might also want to do a case sensitive matching like

```
$select1=Select-String -Path $filePath -Pattern "Final result:" -CaseSensitive
```

Well I tried to simulate your scenario with below text in file *sample.txt*

```
Final result: hey there get lost
hi buddy you come in plz
you need to come early
Final result: hey hello
```

Then when run your command it have multiple matches and thus `Line` array is `null`. So instead of checking for `$select1.Line.Length -gt 0` you should just check the `Length` property like

```
$select1.Length -gt 0
```

Comment: even iam wondering where i have gone wrong this is very critical to me output :D:\Sysdba\Summary1.txt:2:  Final result:                  Passed D:\Sysdba\Summa
ry1.txt:10:  Final result:                  Passed
Does not contain String $select1 is giving below output but $select1.line.length is 0 any reasons why?? i use case sensitive but still same

Comment: $select1 = Select-String -Pattern "Final result:" -Path $filePath this it has data but $select1.line.length is 0

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$a = "test" | out-File C:\temp\text1.txt
```

if you call $a back it has no value

With this:

```
$a = "test"

Set-Content -Value $a -Path C:\temp\text1.txt
or 
$a | Out-File C:\temp\text1.txt
```

$a has the value test

You need to store your value in a variable and then output it to a file or use Tee-Object as JosefZ suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
$select1 = Select-String -Pattern "Final result:" -Path $filePath | 
    Out-File D:\temp\pattern.txt
```

but [**`Out-File`** does not generate any output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file). Hence, `$select1` is always `$null`. Use [`Tee-Object` cmdlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object) instead as follows:

```
$select1 = Select-String -Pattern "Final result:" -Path $filePath | 
               Tee-Object -FilePath  "D:\temp\pattern.txt"
```

**[Tee-Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object) SYNOPSIS:**

> Saves command output in a file or variable and also sends it down the
>   pipeline.

### Edit.

**[`Select-String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) Finds text in strings and files:**

> **INPUTS:**
>
> ```
> System.Management.Automation.PSObject
> ```
>
> You can **pipe** any object that has a `ToString` method to
>   `Select-String`.
>
> **OUTPUTS:**
>
> `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo` or `System.Boolean`
>
> By default, the output is **a set** of *MatchInfo* objects, one for
>   each match found. If you use the `Quiet` parameter, the output is a
>   *Boolean* value indicating whether the pattern was found.

**A set**: one needs to distinguish

- an *empty set* from
- a *one-element set* and from
- a *multi-element set*

For instance, the following code snippet could help:

```
Function getMatchInfoInfo ( $MatchInfoObject )
{
    $MatchInfoObjectLength=0
    $MatchInfoObjectCount =0
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($MatchInfoObject)) {
            # no match
    } else {
        if ( $MatchInfoObject.GetType().Name -eq 'MatchInfo') {
            # one match
            $MatchInfoObjectCount =1
            $MatchInfoObjectLength=$MatchInfoObject.Line.Length
        } else  {
            # multiple matches
            $MatchInfoObjectCount =$MatchInfoObject.Line.Count
            $MatchInfoObject | ForEach-Object { $MatchInfoObjectLength += $_.Line.Length}
        }
    }
    ($MatchInfoObjectCount, $MatchInfoObjectLength)                   ### return array
}

$filePath = 'D:\PShell\SO\Files\f44943410.txt'                        ### individual
$select0 = Select-String -Pattern "XFinal Xresult:" -Path $filePath
$x0 = getMatchInfoInfo $select0
Write-Host "select0: $($x0[0]) match(es) of summary length $($x0[1])"

$select1 = Select-String -Pattern "Final result:" -Path $filePath | 
               Tee-Object -FilePath "$env:TEMP\pattern.txt"
$x1 = getMatchInfoInfo $select1
Write-Host "select1: $($x1[0]) match(es) of summary length $($x1[1])"

$select2 = $select1.Line | Select-String -Pattern "Passed"             ### pipe
$x2 = getMatchInfoInfo $select2
Write-Host "select2: $($x2[0]) match(es) of summary length $($x2[1])"
```

**Output**:

```
PS D:\PShell> .\SO\q44943410.ps1

select0: 0 match(es) of summary length 0
select1: 2 match(es) of summary length 60
select2: 1 match(es) of summary length 24
```

Comment: $select1=Select-String -Pattern "Final result:" -CaseSensitive -Path $filePath |Tee-Object D:\temp\pattern.txt
##$select1.Line |Out-File D:\temp\pattern.txt

write-host($select1) 

#write-host($select1.Matches.Count)

if($select1.Line.Length -gt 0 )  @JoseF $select1 has data why its length is not coming

Answer (score 0):

neways guys all answers are correct , but was not working so i just checked if $select is null or not like
if($select)

{

}
else
{
}

it solved my  purpose thanks a lot